# Java process cpu usage increases

Tags: java, optimization, cpu-usage

I have a multi-player java game server. Everything was working stable since my last additions to the code. What can be the cause of unusual cpu usage spikes? After starting the server, it's around 10-20%. After some time, like 1-2 hours, cpu jumps to 107% and 207% and so on. After 10 hours, it will probably be 1109%.
I am using netty, c3p0. Running this on a powerful dedicated ubuntu machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this without knowing anything about how your software works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer without details, but a good start is to use tools to diagnostic the program behavior.

Using JVisualVM (bundled with the JDK) can help you find if CPU is used by your program or garbage collector.

A memory leak can lead the garbage collector to run excessively.

Comment: http://imgur.com/dolwJem from this memory/cpu view, can you identify whether it can be a memory leak?

Comment: There was a possible infinite loop, I found it and now it's fixed. Thanks for sharing JVisualVM.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://m.javaworld.com/community/node/8036

Probably you have some form of memory leak.

Comment: memory stays the same, when I asked this question (15 mins ago) cpu was 409%-410%. Now it's showing 610%. Can a deadlock cause this?

Comment: http://imgur.com/dolwJem this image shows memory, cpu and load average. 06:00 is the maintenance time, that's why usage is low at that time.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing whole code, I found an infinite loop which could happen in some cases. JVisualVM helped me find this bug.

Thanks for the help.